# Booleans in Angular 4 templates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4.

I have a simple component called Price Difference. I want to decide whether to show the header or not:

```
<price-difference showHeader="true"></price-difference>
```

And in PriceDifferenceComponent:

```
@Input() showHeader: boolean;
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="header-container" *ngIf="showHeader == true">
    <h3>some header</h3>
</div>

showHeader is {{ showHeader }}
<br /> 
showHeader == true is {{ showHeader == true }}
```

The header doesn't show even though `showHeader` is `true`. In the template I see:

```
showHeader is true 
showHeader == true is false
```

Go figure that one out.

How do I get the template to treat showHeader as a boolean value?

Comment: The header will show as I've passed in true for showHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the `[ ]` around binded variable:

`<price-difference [showHeader]="true"></price-difference>`